# About the implementation of Haskell's type classes

Tags: haskell, typeclass

In several of Simon Peyton Jones's presentations, there is a page which shows the history of Type Classes:

[image]

There are quite a lot of materials to understand type classes from a programmer's view, such as the typeclassopedia article and many other tutorials. However its implementation and overhead are seldom described.

I am wondering what were the problems during the implementations and their solutions (I think there should be academic publications for the solutions).

In other words, I am searching materials like *Inside the C++ Object Model*, but for the Haskell language.

Comment: @Sibi the answer in the above question is far from satisfactory. Implementing the typeclass in the original paper is easy. The hard part lies in the "Higher-kinded polymorphism", type classes such as Monads. But I am no expert in programming, so I am asking this question.

Comment: There is no real extra complication in adding higher kinds.  It's a simple matter of changing the type checker a little.

Comment: @YinZhu You might also be interested in the following posts (Edward Yang mentions some of the disadvantages of typeclasses) : http://blog.ezyang.com/2014/07/type-classes-confluence-coherence-global-uniqueness/ and http://blog.ezyang.com/2014/09/open-type-families-are-not-modular/

Comment: @YinZhu Also if you are interested in Edward's exciting work on backpack (which he mentions in the link above) you can have a look at http://web.mit.edu/~ezyang/Public/backpack-manual.pdf